# Translations not working when printing report

Tags: python, odoo-13

I have a custom module for odoo V13, and I am trying to get translations working.

These are the steps I have followed:

1. Add the language (in this case 'french', 'fr' to odoo). Load and replace existing values.
2. Export the `.pot` and the  `fr.po` file from settings > translations > export data
3. Complete the translations using poedit
4. Place the `.pot` and `.po` files in the `i18n' folder which is in the root of my module folder
5. Uninstall my module, restart the server, and re-install my module
6. Verified the translations worked by re-exporting `fr.po`. All my translations are present.
7. Create a company with the language set to 'French (fr)'
8. Print my report

Unfortunately, the report is always printed in English. I had initially been using `--dev all` when launching the server, which blocks the translation engine. I have since removed it and confirmed that other reports (the default ones that come with odoo) are correctly translated.

A few things I have noted but am not sure if they are an issue:

1. There is no mention of my translations in `__manifest__.py`
2. There is no code in my report's model that has to do with translations

This is how the report is structured (irrelevant stuff removed):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <template id="report_delivery_slip">
        <t t-call="web.html_container">
            <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
                <t t-call="co7_reports.report_delivery_slip_document" t-lang="o.partner_id.lang"/>
            </t>
        </t>
    </template>
    <template id="report_delivery_slip_document">
        <t t-call="web.external_layout">
            <t t-set="o" t-value="o.with_context(lang=o.partner_id.lang)" />
            <div class="page">
             report content
            </div>
        </t>
    </template>
</odoo>
```

And here is the python code that generates the report:

```py
@api.model
    def _get_report_values(self, docids, data=None):
        report_obj = self.env['ir.actions.report']
        report = report_obj._get_report_from_name('co7_reports.report_delivery_slip')
        docs = self.env[report.model].browse(docids)
        
        custom logic omitted...

        docargs = {
            'doc_ids': docids,
            'doc_model': report.model,
            'docs': docs,
        }
        return docargs
```

During debugging, I can confirm that the `doc.partner_id.lang` is `fr_FR`, which is the code that corresponds to ISO `fr`. My `.po` file is called `fr.po`.

It is worth mentioning that the line `<t t-set="o" t-value="o.with_context(lang=o.partner_id.lang)" />` works correctly, as the product name is displayed in french. The rest of the report is not.

I am using odoo community, developing in pycharm and launching the server with:

`--addons-path "./addons, ./co7_addons" -d **** -r **** -w ****`

Another interesting fact: If I change my UI language to french, the name of the report is translated correctly (in the print menu of the record). The name is translated in the same file that the report is, `fr.po` in the `i18n` folder.

Comment: For this, Go to the customer for which you want to change the language of reports and change the language of the customer displayed under the language field.

Comment: @GautamBothra This is already done. The customer is set to French